# Sending data form ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, forms, post, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form build using a ng-repeat module:

```
form-{{$index}}-id
form-{{$index}}-value
```

This is the HTML of the form:

```
<input type="text" id="form-0-id" />
<input type="text" id="form-0-value />
<input type="text" id="form-1-id" />
<input type="text" id="form-1-value />
```

I need to send input text values as form data, not as query string.
I must use AngularJS to do that, i can't use the old classic  button and the POST refresh.

```
FORM DATA

form-0-id:"x"
form-0-value:"y"
form-1-id:"a"
form-1-value:"b"
```

exc...

How can i achieve that?
I've already a function that transform data from query string to form data:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {

    // Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

    // Override $http service's default transformRequest
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data)
    {
        return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? jQuery.param(data) : data;
    }];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have over-complicated this issue, you have a list of items that you want to POST back to a server.

Define a controller which will manage this list, and handle the post action via [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

```js
var module = angular.module('testApp', []);

module.controller('MyCtrl', function($http){
  var self = this;
  self.items = [
    {prompt: 'prompt 1', value: 'value 1'},
    {prompt: 'prompt 2', value: 'value 2'},
    {prompt: 'prompt 3', value: 'value 3'}
  ];
  
  self.submitMe = function(){
    var url = 'http://serverUrl'
    
    //sample post code:
    //$http.post(url, self.items);
    
    //debug:
    alert('post data to ' + url + '\n' + JSON.stringify(self.items));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as my">
<form ng-submit="my.submitMe()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in my.items">
      {{item.prompt}} <input type="text" ng-model="item.value"/ >
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. There's a main problem in your answer: the structure. You have the same structure, composed by two fields: prompt and value. I would like to POST something like form-0-id: a, form-0-value: b; form-1-id: c, form-1-value: d and so on... I don't know how to obtain a structure like that one.

Comment: `prompt` and `value` are two separate values, I just typed them to be the same, they can be whatever values you'd like to see, I will update to reflect this.

Comment: But how can i send to the server only the value of the items? I mean, i strictly need data in this way: form-1: x, form-2: y ecc... In a key-value structure the problem is not the value but the key, it must be dynamic, as i previously shown (KEY -> form-1 VALUE -> X, form-2 ; y exc...) Using your method how can i obtain that?

Comment: In my example you can map the values that are being posted to the server into whatever format you need. It captures the submit event and there you can create a new data structure that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ;) How can i map them? Should i use the transformRequest previously posted?

Comment: No, in the controller you now have the model that you can transform/adjust/alter/change any way you see fit via JavaScript before making the `$http.post` call.